# Swipe and advance javascript functionality enabling in Opera Mini like Flipkart Snapdeal and Amazon

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, progressive-enhancement, opera-mini, progressive-web-apps

How can we enable advance Java-script functionalities which only works with work with Opera Mini high mode also work with Opera Mini Extreme Data saving mode, is this only possible with the Opera Side by allowing the specific domain to work like High Mode always.

I have also checked some Progressive Web Apps which are well developed by good developers but still these are not working as the way Flipkar Lite, Snapdeal, Amazon.com is working.